# Excel: Letting the user choose parameter for a SQL connection

Tags: sql, excel, date, odbc

My Excel file is retrieving data from Netezza with a ODBC SQL connection.
To avoid charging too many data I have a clause where in my script:

[image: Sorry it's in French]

Now, I want to let the user choose the date of the WHERE clause. On the first sheet of the file. I have a date written manually on the first cell (A1): 30/09/2023

I want to update automatically the date of the WHERE clause of the SQL script with this one. How should I do?

Thanks for replies